# AngularJS $http.post headers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I am trying to do a http post, but I cant make it work, I am having a 405 Method Not Allowed, but when I do with a plugin of Chrome works perfectly

```
post: function(userData){
    var promise = $http.post(url, userData)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('post success');
            console.log('data');
            console.log(data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('post error');
        console.log('data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('status');
        console.log(status);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

This are the headers when it doesnt work

> Response Headers HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Date: Thu, 13 Mar
>   2014 05:45:39 GMT Allow: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD Content-Type:
>   application/xml;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked Request
>   Headers User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0)
>   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Origin:
>   null Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type Connection: keep-alive
>   Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache

This are the headers when it work

> Request headers  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117
>   Safari/537.36 Origin:
>   chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo Content-Type:
>   application/json  Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 Response headers  Date: Thu, 13 Mar
>   2014 05:44:05 GMT  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Content-Type:
>   application/json;charset=UTF-8  Content-Encoding: gzip  Vary:
>   Accept-Encoding  Transfer-Encoding: chunked

I am trying to change the headers in AngularJS but seems not to be working

thank you

Comment: From the header I found in the first one (doesn't work), you have `Origin: null` while the second one (work) you have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. I think this is because the CORS setting on the server you tried to connect. It failed because the server did allow the request from your origin address. You may need to check the server side CORS setting I think.

Comment: @dfsq My bad, I mean HTTP Request fields

Comment: @ShaunXu thank you.
If I run my local server I change the origin, but get the same error
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Now I will try to check the server side.